# It is not possible to display user data on the Xamarin page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a method that saves user data from a request:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var loginResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponse>(responseContent);

    if (loginResponse != null && loginResponse.user != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginResponse.access_token))
    {
        UserData user = new UserData
        {
            name = loginResponse.user.name,
            email = loginResponse.user.email,
            created_at = loginResponse.user.created_at,
        };
        BindingContext = user;
        await DisplayAlert("Успех", "Авторизация прошла успешно", "OK");
    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Произошла ошибка при авторизации: Неверный формат ответа", "OK");
    }
}
else
{
    await DisplayAlert("Ошибка", "Произошла ошибка при авторизации", "OK");
}
```

The UserData.cs model:

```
public class LoginResponse
{
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public UserData user { get; set; }
    public string access_token { get; set; }
}

public class UserData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
}
```

I need to output on this page, I'm trying to do it, but nothing is output. I don't quite understand how this should happen, watching a video about it I didn't understand anything either:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="#2196F3" Padding="0,20,0,10">
    <Image Source="user_avatar.png" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <Label Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="24" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" />
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout Padding="20">
    <Label Text="Дополнительная информация" FontSize="Title" TextColor="#2196F3" />
    <Label Text="{Binding email}" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: The binding for `name` and `email` wont work because there is no `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation. Data binding doesn't know the property has changed unless you implement this interface. The modern way to do this is using the MVVM Toolkit source generators to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for you.

Comment: that shouldn't matter since he is manually assigning the `BindingContext` after the data is retrieved.  Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to verifying the data is actually getting set correctly?

Comment: When debugging in the method, I get all the user data correctly: [0:] Получен пользователь: Ivan, Email: ivan@gmail.com, Создан: 02.11.2023 16:48:26

Comment: Hi @ДанилГрицан,   where do you call code `if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode){ //....}`? Could you please share the code of  `YourPage.xaml.cs` ?

Comment: Hi @Jessie Zhang, I'm calling the code on the LoginPage page.xaml using a button with an event handler, which seems to save data to the model, debugging says that the data has been received, but output it on the UserProfile page.xaml fails

Comment: I would send the code from LoginPage.xaml.cs, but the comment restrictions do not allow

Comment: [edit] your question, do not include code in comments

Answer (score 0):

Just as Jason mentioned, you can first recheck if you have received the right data from the response of your API. For this, you can debug your code step by step to check the response and to verify the data is got and set correctly.

Besides, if you want UI refresh itself after updating the value of the bond object(`BindingContext = user;`), you can implement interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your viewmodel(`UserData`)

For more information, you can check document: [ViewModels and Property-Change Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-mode#viewmodels-and-property-change-notifications).

Comment: Please come back to this post :)

Comment: Hi @ДанилГрицан,  you can edit your problem and copy your code snippets there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a call to your API after you get succes code. AS I see, you just got an succes code but not the information that you need. You can not fill your page with only success code. Information comes after success code.

My solution below:

```
public async Task<List<BarkodBilgi>> getBarkodBilgi()
    {
        try
        {
            var myValue = Preferences.Get("myServiceIP", "");
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string url = $"ServiceURL"
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            Console.WriteLine(url);
            string cevap = "";
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    cevap = "var";

                    // Code 200 - If the API call is sucess
                    // You redirect to another page
                }
                else
                {
                    // Show alert for failed calls
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (cevap == "var")
            {
                var res = await client.GetStringAsync(url);

                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BarkodBilgi>>(res);
                return result;
            }
            return null;
            // return result;

        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }

    }
```